# How can I load UCI Satellite Data Set?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The codes I tried and the output is below.

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/satimage/sat.trn') 
test_data = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/satimage/sat.tst')
```

When I try to print train_data
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtOa9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the file is not comma separated. It is space separated. The default separator for read_csv is a comma.

You can set a custom separator by using the "sep" parameter in read_csv.

Another problem is that it infers the first row as the column names. You can disable this feature by setting the "header" parameter of read_csv as None.

See below for working code:

```
import pandas as pd

train_data = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/satimage/sat.trn', sep=' ', header=None)
test_data = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/satimage/sat.tst', sep=' ', header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

To download the data first click on the Data Folder which well take you to a second page (lower half of the following picture), here you click on the file you want to download. The . data file can be opened with Microsoft Excel or Notepad. You can see that all the data points are separated with a comma.